# Sort a Range before pasting Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to copy a particular range from a `Workbook` to another `Workbook`, its working fine.

But now i need to sort the `Range` in ascending  order just before pasting to the destination sheet without changing the source. Please help.

```
With Workbooks(strExcelFile).Sheets(strSheetName)
     .Range(strRange).Copy
End With

ActiveSheet.Range(strDestCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Why not paste to the destination and then sort using Range.Sort?

Comment: @Joe: seems to be a good idea, but how to get the range for the destination, since i'm mentioning only  a single cell such as E1 or F1 in the strDestCell?(I'm new to excel VBA)

Comment: Approach that uses a single destination cell *without* copying or select below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that once you paste, your newly pasted range will be selected; then you can use SELECTION.

```
Public Sub test()
     Range("A1:A8").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.Sort key1:=Range("B1")
End Sub
```

That test example will work in any excel file with some data in A1-A8.  B1 in both places can be replaced with strDestCell and A1:A8 with strRange for your eventual subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid the redundant `Select` when working with ranges. You can work more cleanly using `worksheets` and `ranges` as below, which is easily adaptable accross workbooks as per your question

**code**

```
Sub ReCut()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A10")
    With ws2.[b1].Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, 1)
        .Value = rng1.Value
        .Sort ws2.[b1]
    End With
End Sub
```