# How do I sort a range in excel based a user defined value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

In "sheet 1", there are 20 cells in a single column which are drop down boxes where the user selects values (a material from a list of materials). Each material has a property, either High or Low.

What I want to happen:

- When the range of cells  (which contain names of raw materials by the
  way) is pasted into "New Sheet", I want them to be immediately sorted
  into "High" and a "Low" categories. So all the "high" materials are
  at the top and the "bottom" of the range.

So for example in Sheet 1:

```
Material A

Material B

Material C

Material D

.. and so on
```

and this list is in a random HIGH/Low order.

In the "New Sheet", I want to have:

```
Material D

Material A

Material C

Material B
```

where D and A are "High" and C and B are "Low"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say High and Low what do you mean exactly? That the values introduced are higher than an especific value? Or that the materials have a related High/Low value? If you could be more specific with the example it would be easier to know what you want to do.

Comment: yes to the second option. Each material has a property which can be described as either high or low

Comment: from the op it seems pretty clear that he means the values `high` and `low`, although the exact values are kinda irrelevant for the question itself. Different ways to do this, a quick and dirty one would be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017717/sort-a-range-before-pasting-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is in the A1:B20 range you can achieve what you want with this simple macro...

```
Sub Macro4()



Range("A1:B20").Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("B1:B20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```